# é possível que o usuário edite a sessão?

Tags: php

Bom no meu site eu uso certificado SSL, e na sessão eu armazeno alguns dados de acesso. Tem alguma forma do usuário alterar esses dados? Ou da forma que estou fazendo é seguro?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**PHP SESSION**

O uso da variável $_SESSION é muito comum e extremamente difundido, muito seguro mas apresenta dois pontos que podem ser "inseguros":

O primeiro é chamado "*session fixation*". Basicamente, como o ID da sessão é armazenado em um *COOKIE*, este mesmo ID pode ser mudado para o de outro usuário. Isso não é um problema se o usuário receber um ID a cada nova Sessão, tornando muito difícil encontrar um ID ativo em uma Sessão para roubá-lo ([hijacking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6483092/php-session-hijacking) <sup>En</sup>).

O segundo ponto depende do código. Se o seu código expõe as informações secretas armazenadas no $_SESSION então é inseguro. Se o seu código permite que o usuário altere os valores dessas informações, então é inseguro. Ademais se você armazena algo em uma variável $_SESSION e o código nunca permite ao usuário ver/editar essa informação, então é seguro sim.

Tradução livre [daqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5121819/3956218).

Você pode ler mais nessa [Discussão](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121766/can-a-user-alter-the-value-of-session-in-php) (Inglês) ou mesmo no próprio [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.session.php) tem muita informação acerca de Sessões e segurança.

Comment: bom o código apenas consulta a variável $_SESSION para verificar se o usuário tem um determinado privilégio.